# JSP page is not getting reflected in Jetty

Tags: jsp, jetty

I am using Jetty web server, and while loading JSP page, its getting loaded from cache and not from the server. my updated jsp page is not getting reflected. I was deleted my file and checked out from CVS also. There is no use, the same result came again.

What will be the reason ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you exclude the webbrowser from being suspect? I.e. it is not caching the HTML page generated by JSP? Clear browser cache, Ctrl+F5, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have cleared my browser cache and pressed Ctrl + F5, my problem still didn't resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was getting resolved when deleting my jsp file in the temp directory of the jetty-8080 in folder. Go to RUN dialog box, and give %TEMP%, it will display the temp. directory and there I find the directory called jetty-8080, and I deleted jsp file which is generated with .java and .class. Now my problem was resolved.